# Compose: Dotted underline an Annotated String

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am using an `AnnotatedString` to show my text on UI.

```
buildAnnotatedString {
     append(text1)
     append(text2)

     // This text should be dotted underline
     withStyle(style = SpanStyle(textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline)) {
        append(text3)
    }
}
```

It shows a full underline instead of a dotted underline and there is no such style in `TextDecoration`. Is there a way to show `AnnotatedString` in dotted underline style?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is currently not possible in Jetpack Compose. You can consider to open a feature request on the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) for a `TextDecoration.DashedUnderline` or similar. 
For now, you can workaround this by drawing behind a `Text` Composable like this:

```
val pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(floatArrayOf(10f, 10f), 0f)
Text(
    modifier = Modifier.drawBehind {
        val strokeWidthPx = 1.dp.toPx()
        val verticalOffset = size.height - 2.sp.toPx()
        drawLine(
            color = Teal200,
            strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx,
            start = Offset(0f, verticalOffset),
            end = Offset(size.width, verticalOffset),
            pathEffect = pathEffect
        )
    },
    text = text
)
```

If you want to apply this logic to multiple lines of text, please have a look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70697948/how-do-i-make-a-dotted-dashed-underline-for-text-in-jetpack-compose).